# Name for similar beginnings or endings exhibited by sets of nouns / compound nouns etc (not affixes)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I remember knowing a term for "beginnings or endings" that are similar in many words. Not suffixes or prefixes.

I knew this term a long time ago but for some reason I can't recall it. I don't even remember examples but I'll try to make some up.

e.g. English Stackexchange, Biology Stackexchange, Chemistry stackexchange.

All these words have "stackexchange" ending. What is this "stackexchange" called? It's not suffix.

Another example: internet, internal, interjection, interest. All these words have "inter" in common. What's it called?

I apologize if there is the same existing question but finding it would be easy only if I knew the name and I don't know the name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be [cranberry morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme)?

Comment: If you're interested in any Rhetorical Device names of different kinds of repetition, you can look here: [Figures of Repetition](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Repetition.htm)

Comment: In the first set of examples, *Stackexchange* is a noun, and the words that precede it are attributive nouns. The second set of examples describes something completely different. Either you have two different questions, or you're confusing the two different examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cranberry morpheme* might be what you're looking for.

> **Cranberry morpheme:** In linguistic morphology, a cranberry morpheme (or fossilized term) is a type of bound morpheme that cannot be assigned an independent meaning or grammatical function, but nonetheless serves to distinguish one word from another.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - **Mit** in permit, commit, transmit, remit, and submit, from the Latin verb mittere meaning to give, to send.
> - **Ceive** in receive, perceive, and conceive, from the Latin verb capere meaning to seize.
> - **Twi** in twilight.
> - **Cob** in cobweb, from the obsolete word coppe for a spider
>
> Many elements in English toponyms, such as **-ing** ("Reading," "Dorking," "Washington") from an Old English term meaning "the people of."

— **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme)**

Comment: I am convinced. Deleting previous answer.

Comment: I doubt the OP was actively looking for *cranberry morpheme*. :-) How does *cranberry morpheme* work for the Stack Exchange part of the question?

Comment: @RichardKayser, Good point. However, .... *I don't even remember examples but I'll try to make some up.

e.g. English Stackexchange* -> **Cranberry morpheme** may be what the OP is looking for. They clearly say 'I don't even remember examples'. :)

Comment: We have another comedian. :-)

Comment: I wanted to delete this question but I cannot because you have posted an answer. "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center." so I will accept this answer and delete my account. Thank you so much @DecapitatedSoul